# svnadmin load error -> loads first revisions again

Tags: svn, backup, restore, svnadmin

I running a svn server on Ubuntu 12.04 and made a svn backup via:

```
svnadmin dump ./backup/repo > repo.dump
```

Now I tried to restore it and made a new repo via:

```
svnadmin create repo
svnadmin load ./repo < ./backup/repo.dump
```

But after revision 83 it gets weird and I get the following error:

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 83
     * editing path : test/file1.WBG ... done.
     * editing path : test/file2.WBG ... done.

------- Committed revision 83 >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
     * adding path : pic2.png ... done.

------- Committed new rev 84 (loaded from original rev 1) >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 2
     * adding path : pic.png ... done.

------- Committed new rev 85 (loaded from original rev 2) >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 3
     * deleting path : pic.png ... done.
     * deleting path : pic2.png ... done.

------ Committed new rev 86 (loaded from original rev 3) >>>

 <<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 4
 svnadmin: File already exists: filesystem 'repo/db', transaction '86-2e', path 'api'
     * adding path : api ...
```

And then it stops but the whole repository has 90 revisions.

I don't really get why it loads from the first revisions after 83.

I hope someone can help.
Thanks!